# How to install syncfusion javascript using nuget from visual studio community 2022 and visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, syncfusion

I tried the link here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.JavaScript/

```
Install-Package Syncfusion.JavaScript -Version 19.4.0.47
```

From inside VS 2022 community I can not find nuget GUI so I used the console and I get this
[image]

I tried from nuget.exe and get this
[image]

I tried in vs code I pressed `Ctrl+Shit+P` and typed nuget to install nuget GUI but nothing found. What I should do ?

Answer (score 1):

To install the NuGet packages in Visual Studio through package manager Console, run the command under Package Manager tab.

```
 Install-Package Syncfusion.JavaScript -Version 19.4.0.47
```

[install-package-visual-studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIPcB.png)

To install NuGet packages in the Visual Studio Code, please run the below command in the Visual Studio Code terminal which is under .NET CLI tab in the nuget.org

```
 dotnet add package Syncfusion.JavaScript –version 19.4.0.47
```

[install-package-vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYVB1.png)

For more details to install NuGet packages in the application, please refer the below link:
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/nuget-packages/